# Kendo Grid/Kendo Menu Selection Issue in IE Version 10.0.9200.16438

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, kendo-grid, kendo-menu

We are making use of Kendo UI Grid/Kendo Menu in our application. We have selectable() enabled for Kendo UI Grid and it works as expected in all the browsers IE,Firefox and in Google Chrome. Users will be able to select a row in the Grid and will be able to select an item in the Kendo Menu.

But its failing in the Internet Explorer Version 10.0.9200.16438. We are unable to select a row in the Kendo Grid. Similarly we are not able to select a menu item in the Kendo Menu also.

Any help would be highly appreciated.